# How to automatically pick a "mode" for Ace Editor, given a file extension

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, ace-editor

I'm working on a project that uses a java/scala backend ([Lift](http://liftweb.net/), to be precise, though that shouldn't affect this question), and as part of the frontend we use [Ace Editor](http://ace.ajax.org/). I've been googling for a while and have yet to find an answer to this question:

Given a file extension (e.g. `js`, `c`, `cpp`, `h`, `java`, `rb`, etc), how can I automatically pick an Ace "mode" for the appropriate language?

I'm hoping to avoid manually creating a map, a la `js -> javascript, c -> c_cpp, java -> java`. Is there a java/scala library available for this? Or better yet, does Ace have this functionality built in somehow?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ace now provides modelist extension to do this.

```
var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist")
var filePath = "blahblah/weee/some.js"
var mode = modelist.getModeForPath(filePath).mode
editor.session.setMode(mode) // mode now contains "ace/mode/javascript".
```

Note that if you are using [prebuilt](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds) version of ace you need to include `ace.js` and `ext-modelist.js` files in your page.
With source version, you need to replace `ace.require` with `require` and require.js will load all dependencies automatically.

See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/modelist.html and https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/demo/modelist.html for examples of how to use it

Comment: Was this merged? How to use it now?

Comment: Updated the answer to include links to ace demo pages.

Comment: Thank you sir! and here is your upvote. Added the exact command to the answer to make it easier to find.

Comment: Does not work for me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getModeForPath' of undefined` - `ace.require` returns undefined :(

Comment: did you include `ext-modelist.js` file as shown in the demo?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. This is a more updated version that I used in my Django project.

```
    <script src="{% static 'ace/src-noconflict/ace.js' %}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ace/src-noconflict/ext-modelist.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'ace/src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js' %}"></script>
```

```
<script>
    var modelist = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.renderer.setScrollMargin(40, 150)
    document.getElementById('editor').style.fontSize = '15px';
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/dracula");

    var full_path = "{{ file.directory_path }}";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = full_path
    var mode = modelist.getModeForPath(full_path);//mode
    console.log(mode);
    editor.session.setMode(mode.mode);
    //Ace editor autocompletion
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });

</script>
```

Comment: full path = /folder/otherFolder/file.conf

Comment: editor.setOptions({
            enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
            enableSnippets: true,
            enableLiveAutocompletion: true
        });

Answer (score 0):

**The key is editor.session.setMode(mode.mode);**

```
<!-- ace editor -->
<script src="/ace/v1_4_11/ace.js"></script>
<script src="/ace/v1_4_11/ext-modelist.js"></script>
<script src="/ace/v1_4_11/ext-language_tools.js"></script>

let editor = null;      // reference to the Ace editor
let aceModeList = null; // used by the Ace editor

function initializeAceEditor() {
    aceModeList = ace.require("ace/ext/modelist");
    editor = ace.edit("aceEditorDiv");
}

// load the file and set the file-extension specific mode
let mode = aceModeList.getModeForPath(fileName); // detects for example .xml - or any other file extebsion
console.log(`Ace: selected mode = ${mode.mode}`);
try {
    editor.session.setMode(mode.mode);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Ace: No specific mode available for file extension");
}

editor.getSession().setValue(Base64.decode(fileContentB64));
```

There is no need to preload an specific mode *.js file in browser like for example "mode-xml.js". The corresponding mode file is automatically loaded on demand.

Comment: to be more helpful, you coudl include an example of setting the mode based on the file extention as asked.

Comment: In this example, the mode is automatically detected based the on the file extension of "fileName". Any file extensions are supported and the corresponding mode is automatically set. aceModeList.getModeForPath(fileName) does this task - you may have a look at the Ace source.